# How can I create this two merged cells that touch each other without getting a weird distribution?

Tags: html, html-table

[The table I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmcEv.png)

I've started learning HTML recently and currently doing some table exercises. I'm not getting the desired distribution after trying to get a 2-row combined cell and a 2x2 (row and column) combined cell to touch each other and looking like in the image above.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 1px 30px;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td rowspan="2">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">8</td>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>10</td>
            <td colspan="2">11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3" colspan="2">12</td>
            <td>13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>16</td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried this but that doesn't give me the result I want. Do you know what can I do?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "weird distribution"?

Comment: OK now I understand since I ran your snipped and figured out the issue is with the bottom 3 rows that are appearing as 2. Very strange. It _should_ work....

Comment: From experiments, I think you need at least one cell to full exist inside a given row for that row to exist. Eg. If a row's only cells are spanned into other rows, that row collapses and doesn't exist. There might be an attribute/CSS property that disallows this 'row collapse' behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Roddy's comments, the row exists, it just has 0 height. You might have to set a fixed height to force that row to have height. One option (below) is to set it on 18's `tr`. You could also set it on 17's `td`.

If you want the "collapsed" row's height to match 16's row height, you may have to use script to layout, read the height of 16's cell, and set that height on 18's `tr`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 1px 30px;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>16</td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 22px">
            <td rowspan="2">18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That was it, thank you for your help! :)